# Installing KFaenza Icons on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, faenza, icon-themes

I am unable to install the KFaenza Icon set. Steps tried:

- In the Application Appearance section of the KDE System Settings, I clicked on the “download new designs” button. A dialogue pops up which allows you to browse different designs. When clicking on “install”, a few options turn up (apparently different versions). Clicking *any* option leads to an error.
- I visited the corresponding [opendesktop.org page for the KFaenza icon set](http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=143890). Below the description, an array of download options is available. They lead to an expired paste and to “omploader.org” which does not contain a website (the DNS record does not seem to be set up).

  The opendesktop page also has various comments complaining that the resources have vanished, but offer no solution.

How can I install the Faenza icon set for KDE? I could copy the icons over from an old install, but I'd rather not `sudo cp` something into system folders if avoidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### There are many ways to install the icon themes – this is one

Search online for the *KFaenza* theme, e.g. using the search term: “*KFaenza kde rpm*”. A hit: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kfaenza-icon-theme

Download the most recent package: `kfaenza-icon-theme-0.8.9-5.fc20.noarch.rpm`

The RPM can be unpacked to an usable archive with the `rpm2cpio` command (must be installed first):

```
$ rpm2cpio kfaenza-icon-theme-0.8.9-5.fc20.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

This will unpack the *KFaenza* icon theme into the current directory (`./usr/share/icons/KFaenza/...`). The [options for the `cpio` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/html_node/Options.html) can be viewed online: `-i` takes the archive from STDIN, `-d` creates the necessary directories, `-m` preserves modification times (not strictly necessary), and `-v` produces verbose output.

The unpacked `KFaenza` folder then has to be copied over into `~/.kde/share/icons/` to make it available:

[image: Copying the unpacked KFaenza theme with Dolphin]

Now the *KFaenza* theme can be picked from the <kbd>KDE System Settings</kbd> 〉 <kbd>Application Appearance</kbd> 〉 <kbd>Icons</kbd>. Apply the change, and the *KFaenza* is there!

[image: Applying the theme in the system settings]

Comment: Thank you for the very nice answer! It felt weird to use an RPM for a *buntu distro, but as the theme doesn't contain compiled resources … whatever, it works :)